# Microscopic black hole in vacuum

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes

How can we calculate the probability of a field randomly producing enough energy(for a ridiculously short amount of time I guess) in a small enough region to form a black hole?

Is there any calculation made from the current Standard Model(QFT calculation) which gives a precise answer to that?

Comment: This calculation would require a valid theory of quantum gravity, which we don't have yet.

Comment: Can we not calculate  this purely from quantum field theory? All we need is the probability for a certain amount of energy/mass. I would guess that would require some planck masses and volumes as well.

Comment: No, the Standard Model doesn't include gravity.

Comment: Is that because all particles which have mass $m > M_{Planck}$ have volume larger than $V=L_{Planck}^3$? So a particle randomly forming is prohibited by quantum number conservations?

Comment: The closest thing you're going to get is the QFT in curved space-time program.  I would look at Hawkings "Euclidean Quantum Gravity" book, particular the chapters that examine topological transitions.  I think there is a discussion on estimation of probability of such transitions.  However since we don't know what QG is, they are just semi-classical arguments.

Comment: The mass of a BH with Planck length radius would be in the order of a few tenths of a milligram: what is the likelihood such a mass could spontaneously form? In any case, the temperature of this micro BH would be so great that the Hawking radiation would have an energy comparable to the BH's mass, and it would instantly evaporate.